# Get iframe content in python

Tags: python, iframe

I need content of a html pages, but if a html page contains a iframe element, I need iframe content too. (in Python)
Is it possible to load everything with a python function?

Comment: Please check @Martijn Pieters answer at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028664/python-beautifulsoup-iframe-document-html-extract. This is may be help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which [supports iframes out of the box](https://github.com/byrongibson/scripts2/blob/master/python/beautifulsoup/sue-soup-tidy.py).

Code snippet ([full code here](https://github.com/byrongibson/scripts2/blob/master/python/beautifulsoup/sue-soup-tidy.py)):

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment
...
for iframe in mosoup("iframe"):
    mosoup.iframe.extract()
```

**UPDATE:** Linked to current location of code (now in github).

Comment: ignore it, just use the BeautifulSoup parts and adjust them to your needs.

Comment: Strange indeed, I linked to a valid source code snippet back at the time. Will try to find it.

Comment: whoooaaaa! I like how you put it "supports iframes out of box". I'm sold!