# python beautifulsoup iframe document html extract

Tags: python, html, iframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn a bit of beautiful soup, and to get some html data out of some iFrames - but I have not been very successful so far.

So, parsing the iFrame in itself does not seem to be a problem with BS4, but I do not seem to get the embedded content from this - whatever I do.

For example, consider the below iFrame (this is what I see on chrome developer tools):

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"
src="http://www.engineeringmaterials.com/boron/728x90.html "width="728" height="90">
#document <html>....</html></iframe>
```

where, `<html>...</html>` is the content I am interested in extracting.

However, when I use the following BS4 code:

```
iFrames=[] # qucik bs4 example
for iframe in soup("iframe"):
    iFrames.append(soup.iframe.extract())
```

I get:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO" src="http://www.engineeringmaterials.com/boron/728x90.html" width="728" height="90">
```

In other words, I get the iFrames without the document `<html>...</html>` within them.

I tried something along the lines of:

```
iFrames=[] # qucik bs4 example
iframexx = soup.find_all('iframe')
for iframe in iframexx:
    print iframe.find_all('html')
```

.. but this does not seem to work..

So, I guess my question is, how do I reliably extract these document objects `<html>...</html>` from the iFrame elements.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Browsers load the iframe content *in a separate request*. You'll have to do the same:

```
for iframe in iframexx:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(iframe.attrs['src'])
    iframe_soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
```

Remember: BeautifulSoup is not a browser; it won't fetch images, CSS and JavaScript resources for you either.