# How to get data from a python console in iframe

Tags: iframe, console

I am trying to build an e-learning website which helps the users in coding by making them code simple examples. I have integrated an online console from coding guru in an iframe. I wanted to fetch the results from what the user codes and match with the answers in my database to know whether the user has solved the problem correctly or not.

How do I take only the result section from iframe?

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<iframe width='100%' height='550' 
src='https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php' 
allowfullscreen='allowfullscreen' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</html>
```

Comment: Please update your code

Comment: @kvk30, yes done!

Comment: [useful-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028664/python-beautifulsoup-iframe-document-html-extract) use this link it may be useful.