# Can't load contents of an iframe with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need scrape the contents of an iframe using python.

As the web-page loads it submits a request and gets the content of the iframe in the response. When I use BeautifulSoup to get the data it just gives the initial blank iframe contents.

Is there any way I can get the contents? If so, how do I do it in my case?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0x168296bb09e24a88805cb9c33356536b980d3fc5#balances" + "/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x168296bb09e24a88805cb9c33356536b980d3fc5&amp;s=100000000000000000", headers={"content-type":"type"}, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

balances = soup.find(id="balances")
print(balances.prettify()) 
table_items = balances.find_all('tr') #I'm trying to collect all the <tr> tags inside an <iframe>
print(table_items) #It shows an empty list because the <iframe> didn't load
```

Answer (score 0):

You must switch to iframe, to get content from it. Find iframe and then make new request.

```
iframe_content = requests.get(soup.find("iframe_name")["src"])
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028664/python-beautifulsoup-iframe-document-html-extract)  question

Comment: What do you put in the "src" part? I tried putting in the link from the iframe's src but it doesn't work

Comment: Src is iframe`s attribute that specifies the url of the document to embed in the iframe. I didnt visit your url. The src is empty because they use javascript to set it. You can`t get it with bs4. One posible solution is to use Selenium