# How to get information out of a html-document which is embedded in a html website usning bs4 and python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a telegram python bot running on my raspberry pi which gives you information about coronavirus. But now I am having trouble with finding the information from this website :https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/685d0ace521648f8a5beeeee1b9125cd whith bs4 and python. In the `<body>` is an `<iframe>` and in this is a `#document` with a new html file.

How can I get the information out of the `#document` html file?

This was my code for testing:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pager = urllib.request.urlopen("https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/685d0ace521648f8a5beeeee1b9125cd")
inter = BeautifulSoup(pager, 'html.parser')
div = inter.find('iframe')

print(div)
```

but its only outputting 'None'

this is the source code of the website:
[source code of https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/685d0ace521648f8a5beeeee1b9125cd

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028664/python-beautifulsoup-iframe-document-html-extract

Comment: If it's a dynamical loading page maybe BeautifulSoup is not enough. Pls check Selenium!
https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25