# Scrape webpage for a specific text(string)

Tags: python

First post on stackoverflow so I apologize if I am not posting properly. I am trying to scrape a webpage for information only when a specific text string is present. I was only using beautiful soup but could not find the element that contained the text I was looking for. After a bit of more research, I tried using selenium with the understanding that some dynamically loaded elements could not be found on beautiful soup. So far I am still unable to find the text string. The text is locatable when I inspect element.

TLDR: I want to scrape this webpage for the price per share given I can find the text 'public offering price'. Can't find the string when I use beautifulsoup or selenium but I can locate with inspect element (https://docoh.com/filing/829323/0001654954-20-006336/INUV-424B5)

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you add some code to show us what you have already tried...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you be using python and httplib, this will avoid being too far for the mechanism that you need to invoque, and you don't need more than that.

```
import httplib
connection = httplib.HTTP(S)Connection("ip/hostname", port)
req = connection.request("GET", "url")
if(req.read() == "text you are looking for")
    print("found")
```

Obviously you choose either HTTP or HTTPS connection, and replace ip/hostname and url with the desired address and url.

NOTE: you can always use python help module in a oneliner like:
`python -c 'import httplib; help(httplib)'`

Answer (score 0):

I am new to `beautifulsoup` myself but I was able to get the desired output... I will try to show you the entire process from identifying the problem and getting to the solution.

When I inspect the element I got this:
[image]

But when I look at the soup created by the following code, these classes are nowhere to be found:

```py
#code
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = requests.get('https://docoh.com/filing/829323/0001654954-20-006336/INUV-424B5')
soup = bs(page.content,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

The farthest class I could find was `filing-frame` which I noticed was an iframe. So I looked up how to use `beautifulsoup` to get data from iframes. I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028664/python-beautifulsoup-iframe-document-html-extract) about it. The first answer is all that was needed.

Now I haven't used `urllib` much so I stuck with `requests`. Ultimately this is what I came up with :

```py
for iframe in soup("iframe"):
    i_frame= requests.get("https://docoh.com"+iframe.attrs['src'])
    iframe_soup = bs(i_frame.content)
```

Now if I search for the class `agm` in the `iframe_soup` I get the desired result...

```py
print(iframe_soup.find_all("td", {"class": "agm"})[1].text)
#output : '5,500,0000'
```