# Using Beautifulsoup To Scrape iframe

Tags: python, html, iframe, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Hi I would like to scrape with beautiful soup, but normally the iframe src should be an html link, this time I encounter a wordpress URL that is basically the folder structure that leads to the PHP file.

I was wondering if there is any way to scrape the table inside that file?

The table DIV tags exist when I inspect elements in Chrome, howeve, when I loaded the link with BeautifulSoup, the content within the iframe disappears(table).

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python beautifulsoup iframe document html extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028664/python-beautifulsoup-iframe-document-html-extract)

Answer (score 0):

When the contents are loaded by JavaScript or PHP, the ***[Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)*** library can be more useful and handy to extract the required data.