# Python, Web Scrape, Classes

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape for the 1st time. Trying to return the address of each site location listed on the web page based on class. The request seems to not return all data from the html.  I can clearly see that data I want when I inspect the page. Yet I cannot get it to output when running my code.  Keeps showing zero results match my criteria.
I tried find_all 2 different ways.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

language: Python 3.8.5
code:

'''

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

r = requests.get('https://www.medexpress.com/search-result-answers.html?query=Centers+near+me&referrerPageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.medexpress.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('span', class_ = "c-address-street-1")
results2 = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':"c-address-street-1"})
print(len(results))
print(len(results2))
```

'''

Comment: Id say its because its an iframe within the page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python beautifulsoup iframe document html extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028664/python-beautifulsoup-iframe-document-html-extract)

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks. Does that mean i will not be able to extract the data I want, or is there a way around that?

Comment: I just read up on iframes.  Seems I just need to make the correct http requests.  So I need to use the url that's imbedded for that iframe specifically, instead of trying to use the parent page url.